# Help understanding link between module and representation.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, vector-spaces, modules, representation-theory

I posted a related question but was told to break it up into smaller pieces, so here goes.

I am reading *Algebra* by P. M. Cohn, and I am trying to wrap my head around modules and representations. The author wants to establish a link between the two concepts, and writes *[...] take a finite-dimensional $G$-module $V$, with basis $v_1,...,v_d$ over field $k$. The action of $G$ on $V$ is completely described by the equations*
$$\tag{1}
xv_i=\sum_j \rho_{i j}(x) v_j \quad(x \in G)
$$
*where $\rho_{ij}(x)\in k$, and it is easily checked that the matrices $\rho(x)=(\rho_{ij}(x))$ form a representation of $G$*.

What I understand from the above is that since we assume that $V$ is a $G$-module, we know that there exists a multiplication $G\times V\rightarrow V$. Since the product $x v_i$ is in $V$, we know that we can write it as a linear combination of the basis vectors, which is what he does on the right-hand side of eq. $(1)$. I then want to show that the matrices so defined provide a representation. From what I understand, this is true if
$$\tag{2}
\forall x,y\in G :\rho(xy)=\rho(x)\rho(y)\quad \text{and}\quad \rho(\epsilon)=I,
$$
where $\epsilon$ is the identity in $G$ and $I$ the identity matrix. From the definition of a $G$-module, we know that associativity and linearity must hold for the multiplication, so
$$\tag{3}
\begin{aligned}
\sum_j \rho_{i j}(g h) v_j & =(g h) v_i,\quad \text{eq. (1)} \\
& =g\left(h v_i\right), \quad \text {associativity} \\
& =g \sum_j \rho_{i j}(h) v_j, \quad \text { eq. (1) } \qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad (3)\\
& =\sum_j \rho_{i j}(h) g v_j, \quad \text { linearity } \\
& =\sum_j \rho_{i j}(h) \sum_k \rho_{j k}(g) v_k \quad \text{eq.}\ (1)
\end{aligned}
$$
but this is where I get stuck. For eq. $(2)$ to hold, we should have
$$\tag{4}
\sum_j \rho_{i j}(g h) v_j=\sum_j \rho_{i j}(g)\rho_{i j}(h) v_j,
$$
which does not seem to be the case considering eq. $(3)$. So what am I misunderstanding?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Equation (4) is wrong: the $ij$ entry of the product matrix $\rho(g)\rho(h)$ is not $\rho_{ij}(g)\rho_{ij}(h)$ (you don't multiply matrices by multiplying them entry-by-entry).  Instead, the $ij$ entry of the product matrix is $\sum_k \rho_{ik}(g)\rho_{kj}(h)$, which exactly matches what you have in equation (3) (after a relabelling of the variables to swap $j$ and $k$ since there you are looking at the $ik$ entry rather than the $ij$ entry).

Comment: Ah, of course. Thank you!